# Find every occurrence where a substring matches in a list and make a single string

Tags: python, list

I have an array where every row of the list is in the following format
    Element 1[tab]Element2[tab]Element 3[tab]Element 4[eol]

The first 3 elements of each row could have more than one instance in the list, like:

```
11333[tab]55555[tab]EG[tab]455565[EOL]
11332[tab]55555[tab]EG[tab]455563[EOL]
11333[tab]55555[tab]EG[tab]455562[EOL]
```

The last element of each row is variable. What I want to do is to dedupe the list and take the last element of the dupe rows and concatenate them together with a character between them, like:
    11333[tab]55555[tab]EG[tab]455565,455562[EOL]
    11332[tab]55555[tab]EG[tab]455565[EOL]

In order for me to achieve this, I essentially have to iterate between the two lists like this:

```
new_list = []
last_column = ""
for element in list1:
  for otherelement in list 2:
    if last_column == "" :
      last_column += otherelement[3]
    else:
      last_column += "," + otherelement[3]
  new_list.append(element.split(" ")[0:2] + " " + last_column)
```

Not verbatim but it gives you an idea of what I'm doing.
Now keep in mind that each of these lists typically can have at least 10,000 rows each, so that means for every item in the first list, it's checked against all 10,000 items in the other list. Not ideal, and it certainly isn't quick.

Is there a nicer solution that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the previous answer with your actual data:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
  "11333    55555   EG  455565",
  "11332    55555   EG  455563",
  "11333    55555   EG  455562"
]

vars_by_common = defaultdict(list)
for d in data:
  parts = d.split("\t")
  common = tuple(parts[:3])  # so it can be a key in a dict
  var = parts[3]

  vars_by_common[common].append(var)

# now rebuild list
new_data = []
for c, v in vars_by_common.items():
  new_data.append("\t".join(c) + "\t" + ",".join(v))

print(new_data)
```

Comment: That's perfect! Added benefit of not needing to change the format of the existing data. Let me try this out and see how much faster it is.

Answer (score 0):

In order to gather and group the data, a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) seems like a great option. See an example below.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    [1, 1, 1, 'a'],
    [1, 1, 1, 'b'],
    [1, 1, 2, 'c'],
    [2, 1, 1, 'd'],
]

accumulator = defaultdict(list)
for row in data:
    # use a tuple of the first three elements as the key
    # append the fourth element to a list tracking the values
    accumulator[tuple(row[:-1])].append(row[-1])

print accumulator
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {(1, 1, 1): ['a', 'b'], (2, 1, 1): ['d'], (1, 1, 2): ['c']})
```

Getting the data into the form used in this example should be easy enough, and getting the output you want should just be the reverse of that.

Comment: Interesting. I've never worked with tuples outside of some stuff for class. The data must be in the form lists within a list?

Comment: @iros A nested list structure is easiest to show, but the outer container just needs to be an iterable (`for row in data`), and the inner container just needs to be indexable (`row[:-1]` and `row[-1]`).

Comment: @iros Also, a tuple is only necessary because the key in a dictionary should be hashable, and mutable objects (e.g. lists) generally aren't hashable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! The solution of using a defaultdict is much, much, much faster. I never took official timings, but the runs with my solution took a good 6 seconds, now I'm looking at about a second, maybe less. This shows marked improvement when the number of variable items to append becomes larger (obviously).

Only downside is losing order because dicts aren't perfect, I guess. But order doesn't matter for me.

Comment: FWIW, `collections` does have an `OrderedDict` if you do care about order, but then you would have to handle the defaultdict part your self which is as simple as `vars_by_common = OrderedDict()` and `if common not in vars_by_common: vars_by_common[common] = []`

Comment: I was thinking about that this morning. I use OrderedDict in other places in my application but order doesn't matter enough for me to go through the effort of changing it again. Thanks!